# How to install Sympy on Python 3.3 in Windows 7?

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

I have already check Sympy.org website and the following link. But I didn't find any executable file to install the Sympy on Python 3.3.

http://code.google.com/p/sympy/downloads/list

Comment: Is not  sympy-0.7.2.win32.exe enough? Edit: sorry, my bad, you want python 3. Just take the archive sympy-0.7.2-py3.2.tar.gz and uncompress it.

Comment: I did such thing, but what should I do afterward? There is setup.py file which has no effect after run. Should I copy the folder somewhere?

Comment: It all depends on the way you use your environment. In the most basic case `setup.py install` should be enough. Check http://docs.python.org/2/install/ or http://docs.python.org/3/install/

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, we never got `bdist_wininst` working in Python 3. You'll need to install from source.